# Letter digit letter sequence not being detected

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to parse a text to figure our how many ***letter-digit-letter*** sequences are there.

Consider the following string: `a123123aas52342ooo345345ooo`

I used the following regex:

```
re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z]+\d+[a-zA-Z]+", string)
```

The sequences that should be detected are:

- `a123123aas`
- `aas52342ooo`
- `ooo345345ooo`

However, this is what I'm getting:

- `a123123aas`
- `ooo345345ooo`

What am I doing wrong? I have a feeling that regex might not be the solution  to this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: `findall()` doesn't find overlapping sequences.

Comment: @Barmar on second thought it might not be an exact duplicate as suggested solution will give `aas...`, `as....`, and `s...` as results and OP only interested in `aas...`

Comment: @Barmar, yeah I just had a look at the duplicate solution. Didn't work on this one lol. Any thoughts on a potential solution?

Comment: You need to define your requirements more carefully then. Why are some overlapping sequences OK, but not others?

Comment: See if this gets you closer: https://regex101.com/r/LHlQ5G/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little workaround on the "all overlapping matches" answer:

```py
>>> import re
>>> s = "a123123aas52342ooo345345ooo"
>>> print(re.findall("(?<![a-zA-Z])(?=([a-zA-Z]+\d+[a-zA-Z]+))", s))
['a123123aas', 'aas52342ooo', 'ooo345345ooo']
```

This basically says:

- Look ahead and make sure the pattern required is there and save it
- And the added lookbehind makes sure it is the first letter of each letters sequence.

A [demo](https://regex101.com/r/LHlQ5G/2) on your example string.

Answer (score 0):

This simple expression or maybe a bit modified version of that might likely work on our input strings here:

```
[a-zA-Z]+\d+[a-zA-Z]+$|[a-zA-Z]+\d+
```

#### Test with re.findall

```
import re

regex = r"[a-zA-Z]+\d+[a-zA-Z]+$|[a-zA-Z]+\d+"

test_str = "a123123aas52342ooo345345ooo"

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### Output

```
['a123123', 'aas52342', 'ooo345345ooo']
```

#### Test with `re.finditer`

```
import re

regex = r"[a-zA-Z]+\d+[a-zA-Z]+$|[a-zA-Z]+\d+"

test_str = "a123123aas52342ooo345345ooo"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/8RGLoL/1), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/8RGLoL/1debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]